# Open addess in UITextView in Maps Apple Swift

Tags: html, swift, uitextview

I have a html text in UItext View. I use the estensions String for parse it, and work well.

Than I add a WebView for open a ONLY link inside it. (Number telephone, sms, or mail I open with native Apple App)

Now I have a Problem with Address like "1, cupertino California" this is my code

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

if URL.scheme == "mailto" || URL.scheme == "tel" || URL.scheme == "sms" || URL.scheme == "message" {

            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL)
            return true //use native app
        }else{
          //code for open webView
          return false //not use native app 
        }
```

If i use "return true" only, Maps Work well and text View open Address, but in my scenario no.

Why? It's possible open Address from textview using this specific scenario?

thanks

Comment: What's the `URL.scheme` when it's an address?

Comment: `URL: x-apple-data-detectors://embedded-result/1294; URL.scheme: Optional("x-apple-data-detectors")` I don't know why